# Motorcycle: troubling starting/cutting out. Burning rubber smell coming from engine. Electrics failing on and off

Tags: motorcycle

as above really. It's a herald classic 125. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the bike sorry. The burning smell sounds like it could be the clutch, do you notice any slipping?(assuming you've had chance to ride it before it cutting out. The other side I would suspect electrical or fuel, is the fuel fresh? Is it fuel injected or carbeureter?

Comment: Also how does the spark plug look?